# Why won't my divs line up?

Tags: html, css, display

Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>
        Oaki Softworks
    </title>
    <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="navigation">
        <div style="height:20px;width=15%;float:right;">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/oakisoftworks/?fref=ts"><img src="facebook_icon.png" class="social_media_icon"></a>
            <img src="instagram_icon.png" class="social_media_icon">
            <img src="twitter_icon.png" class="social_media_icon">
            <img src="youtube_icon.png" class="social_media_icon">
        </div>
        <div class="navigation_tile">Contact Us</div>
        <div class="navigation_tile">Careers</div>
        <div class="navigation_tile">Products</div>
        <div class="navigation_tile">About Us</div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="blurb">
            <img src="Logo%20(inverted,%20transparent).png" style="width:90%;height:auto;align-self:center;">
            <h2>Video games as art.</h2>
            <p>Even before the conception of our company, we have always embraced video games as the newest, emerging art form. Video games engage an audience like no other medium: allowing them to digest the material at their own pace, to identify themselves within their avatar as they see fit, and to interact with the world around them. Oaki Software aims to underline these elements of art even further with our own game design.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="main_pic">
            <img src="art.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>
            Oaki Softworks&trade;
            <br>Fort Collins, CO 80521
            <br>benkulka@oakisoftworks.com
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS

```
body {
    background-color: #021034;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#navigation {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: black;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    color: #adb7bd;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
}

div.navigation_tile {
    height: 30px;
    width: 15%;
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    margin: 5px;
}

div.navigation_tile:hover {
    background-color: #092466;   
}

div.navigation_tile:active {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

#content {
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: justify;
}

#blurb{
    padding: 40px 0 0 25px;
    width: 28%;
    height: 250px;
}

#main_pic {
    float: right;
    width: 66%;
    height: 250px;
    border: 10px #092466 solid;
    overflow: hidden;
}

h1{
    color: #A5B7E3;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 54px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 58px;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
}

h2 {
    color: #6681C4;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 34px;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}

p{
    text-indent: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', Arial, serif;
    line-height: 20px;
}

img.social_media_icon{
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
}

#footer {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

I'm trying to get my #blurb div to line up with my #main_pic div within my parent #content div, but I'm having trouble doing so. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

```
#blurb {
    [...]
    float: left;
}
#content {
    [..]
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Also consider removing  height: 250px; from #blurb ... hard to say is it required for some reason.